# Keras throwing a labels shape mismatch error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am building a multiclass segmentation model using DeepLapv3+ and ResNet50 to detect facial parts. I started off with [this](https://keras.io/examples/vision/deeplabv3_plus/) tutorial but altered much of the code for my use case.

In this block, I am processing my data:

```
# CIHP has 20 labels and Headsegmentation has 14 labels

image_size = 512
batch = 4
labels = 14
data_directory = "/content/headsegmentation_final/"
sample_train_images = len(os.listdir(data_directory + 'Training/Images/')) - 1
sample_validation_images = len(os.listdir(data_directory + 'Validation/Images/')) - 1
print('Train size: ' + str(sample_train_images))
print('Validation size: ' + str(sample_validation_images))

t_images = sorted(glob(os.path.join(data_directory, "Training/Images/*")))[:sample_train_images]
t_masks = sorted(glob(os.path.join(data_directory, "Training/Category_ids/*")))[:sample_train_images]
v_images = sorted(glob(os.path.join(data_directory, "Validation/Images/*")))[:sample_validation_images]
v_masks = sorted(glob(os.path.join(data_directory, "Validation/Category_ids/*")))[:sample_validation_images]

def image_augmentation(img, random_range):
    img = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(img)
    img = tfa.image.rotate(img, random_range)

    return img

def image_process(path, mask=False):
    img = tf.io.read_file(path)

    upper = 90 * (math.pi/180.0) # degrees -> radian
    lower = 0 * (math.pi/180.0)
    ran_range = random.uniform(lower, upper)

    if mask == True:
        img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=3)
        img.set_shape([None, None, 3])
        img = tf.image.resize(images=img, size=[image_size, image_size])
        #img = image_augmentation(img, ran_range)

    else:
        img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
        img.set_shape([None, None, 3])
        img = tf.image.resize(images=img, size=[image_size, image_size])
        img = img / 127.5 - 1
        #img = image_augmentation(img, ran_range)

    return img

def data_loader(image_list, mask_list):
    img = image_process(image_list)
    mask = image_process(mask_list, mask=True)
    return img, mask

def data_generator(image_list, mask_list):

    cihp_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_list, mask_list))
    cihp_dataset = cihp_dataset.map(data_loader, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    cihp_dataset = cihp_dataset.batch(batch, drop_remainder=True)

    return cihp_dataset

train_dataset = data_generator(t_images, t_masks)
val_dataset = data_generator(v_images, v_masks)

print("Train Dataset:", train_dataset)
print("Val Dataset:", val_dataset)
```

I am using the head-segmentation dataset by mut1ny, which has 14 labels. The images are jpg while the masks are png.

Here is where I am trying to run my epochs:

```
loss = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = True)

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss=loss, metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data = val_dataset, epochs = 50)
```

But this is the error I am met with:

```
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-c69b991cd650> in <module>()
      3 model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss=loss, metrics=["accuracy"])
      4 
----> 5 history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data = val_dataset, epochs = 50)
      6 
      7 plt.plot(history.history["loss"])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 919, in compute_loss
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1863, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
        y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5203, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
        labels=target, logits=output)

    ValueError: `labels.shape` must equal `logits.shape` except for the last dimension. Received: labels.shape=(3145728,) and logits.shape=(1048576, 14)
```

**Update**

Here is an example mask:

[image]

This is how I am loading the model:

```
def DeepLabV3_ResNet50(size, classes):
    input = keras.Input(shape=(size, size, 3))

    resnet50 = keras.applications.ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor = input)
    x = resnet50.get_layer("conv4_block6_2_relu").output
    x = DSP_pooling(x)

    a = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(size // 4 // x.shape[1], size // 4 // x.shape[2]),interpolation="bilinear",)(x)
    b = resnet50.get_layer("conv2_block3_2_relu").output
    b = block(b, filters = 48, kernel = 1)

    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([a, b])
    x = block(x)
    x = block(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(size // x.shape[1], size // x.shape[2]),interpolation="bilinear",)(x)

    output = layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same")(x)

    return keras.Model(inputs = input, outputs = output)

model = DeepLabV3_ResNet50(size = image_size, classes = labels)
model.summary()
```

I've adjusted the shape of the labels. Both the images and masks are RGB. The necessary adjustments were made during dataset processing. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is: you have a 3-channel image, but 14 classes.

You need to transform the images in 14 classes for them to be compatible with the model's output. And, of course, the last layer of the model must have 14 filters to output 14 classes.

So, in a previous phase, before training, you must create a dictionary of colors and attribute an index for each.

One suggestion is to sum RGB in a way it can't be repeated.
Such as:

```
images = load_a_number_of_images_that_have_all_colors()
images = numpy.concatenate(images, axis=0) #maybe not necessary
    #the goal above is to load a shape like (anything, anything, channels)

color_keys = images[:,:,0]*1000000 + images[:,:,1]*1000 + images[:,:,2]
color_keys = numpy.unique(color_keys)

color_dictionary = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(color_keys)
```

Now that you have a color dictionary, I'm not sure what the best strategy is (preprocess the images and save their index arrays, do it on the fly in the loader, etc.). Choose something that will run fast. I believe saving each array would be an interesting idea, but then you'd have to change the loader a lot.

The goal is: in the loader, transform the images into arrays of indices.

```
def image_process(path, mask=False):

        #blablablabla

    if mask == True:
        img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=3)
        img.set_shape([None, None, 3])
        img = tf.image.resize(images=img, size=[image_size, image_size],
              method=ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR) #this is extremely important
              #you don't want slight changes due to interpolation

   
        #img = image_augmentation(img, ran_range) #make sure you use "nearest" here too!!

        img.set_shape([None, 3]) #flattened to make it easier
        color_keys = img[:,0]*1000000 + img[:,1]*1000 + img[:,2]
        img = tf.constant([color_dictionary[k] for k in color_keys])
        img.set_shape([image_size, image_size]) #having an image shape again
```

Comment: My masks are colourful. They're not black/white

Comment: There are 14 classes, they cannot be a normal colored image.

Comment: They're all colorful images. Just black background and the objects are of 14 different colors.

Comment: Well then... you must check the shape of the masks after loading and before training. You must use `channels=0` though, to get the original image channels and avoid problems with the shape. If the shape is still wrong, then you have to reshape manually before training, or in the loading function. And, of course, you need to transform those colors in individual 14 channels for training.

Comment: Look at the post. I've added an example of a mask.

Comment: Also, changing `channels=0` brings the same error. I'll also add how I am loading the model..

Comment: @oo92, I'm trying to write a new answer based on the new info, but I noticed you changed the last layer from `classes` to `3` units. Both options are possible, but they need different adjustments. But only with `classes` you will have a classification problem. With `3` you will have a regression problem and will need later to calculate distances to the target colors for making a custom accuracy.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Maybe write a full answer if you can. You saw what my masks look like for each image and every image only has 1 mask file for all objects of interest. How should I adjust my code?

Comment: @oo92, ok... but what is the difference between light green and dark green? Or light purple and dark purple? Are they class combinations (sums of colors representing base classes)? Or are they individual classes like unique colors?

Comment: The differences are the RGB values and they represent individual classes

Comment: Do you have a solution for this problem?

Comment: @oo92, updated answer

Comment: In `load_a_number_of_images_that_have_all_colors()`, do I load them as numpy arrays?

Comment: In the phase of building a dictionary, yes. The only important thing is: the order of the channels must be the same as `decode_png`. You can do this only once and save this dictionary (you will need it later for using the model)

Comment: How can I ensure the order?

Comment: Also, are the images in `load_a_number_of_images_that_have_all_colors()` masks or just regular images?

Comment: Masks. Verify the images to see if they're equal.